# How to get the 'Value' using 'Key' from json in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have the following Json string. I want to get the 'Value' using 'Key', something like

giving 'BtchGotAdjust' returns 'Batch Got Adjusted';

```
var jsonstring=
[{"Key":"BtchGotAdjust","Value":"Batch Got Adjusted"},{"Key":"UnitToUnit","Value":"Unit To Unit"},]
```

Comment: access it like an array? or did i get your question wrong?

Comment: You need to iterate through your array of objects and compare or use a library like underscoreJS which makes it easy and quick:
`_.findWhere(list, properties) `

Comment: @Ahmad You can use pure js for this, no need for other libraries.

Comment: @Magrangs We can do anything in pure js for sure, But most of us still use them to save time :)

Comment: @Ahmad agreed but this is just a simple problem, the addition of a library is overkill in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow... Looks kind of tough! Seems like you need to manipulate it a bit. Instead of functions, we can create a new object this way:

```
var jsonstring =
    [{"Key":"BtchGotAdjust","Value":"Batch Got Adjusted"},{"Key":"UnitToUnit","Value":"Unit To Unit"},];
     var finalJSON = {};
     for (var i in jsonstring)
         finalJSON[jsonstring[i]["Key"]] = jsonstring[i]["Value"];
```

You can use it using:

```
finalJSON["BtchGotAdjust"]; // Batch Got Adjusted
```

Comment: seems a good aproach, better to loop once and change to dictionary than looping everytime and checking.

Answer (score 3):

As you have an array in your variable, you have to loop over the array and compare against the `Key`-Property of each element, something along the lines of this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonstring.length; i++) {
  if (jsonstring[i].Key === 'BtchGotAdjust') {
    console.log(jsonstring[i].Value);
  }
}
```

By the way, I think your variable name `jsonstring` is a little misleading. It does **not** contain a string. It contains an array. Still, the above code should give you a hint in the right direction.

Comment: better to create a function, which takes a `key` and returns a `value`.

Comment: yes, of course. The code should just demonstrate the approach; OP should wrap this into some function like `getElementByKey`.

Comment: Please not that this approach will loop over the array everytime you want to get an element by its key. If you are going to do this often, refer to Praveen's answer, as that will perform better.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would create a map from the array and then it acts like a dictionary giving you instantaneous access. You also only have to iterate through the array once to get all the data you need:

```
var objectArray = [{"Key":"BtchGotAdjust","Value":"Batch Got Adjusted"},{"Key":"UnitToUnit","Value":"Unit To Unit"}]

var map = {}

for (var i=0; i < objectArray.length; i++){
    map[objectArray[i].Key] = objectArray[i]
}

console.log(map);
alert(map["BtchGotAdjust"].Value)
alert(map["UnitToUnit"].Value)
```

See js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/t2vrn1pq/1/

Comment: Ah just spotted Praveen's answer which is the same concept as mine pretty much. If you are going to accept an answer, pick his over mine as he got there first :-)